# Github - Bitbucket - This repository is over the 4 GB limit even after using Git LFS

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have repo that is over the 4GB limit, I enabled Git LFS and applied it to jpg, png, pdf and mp4 after doing adding those and commiting I still can't push saying I am over my size limit. If I go back to my last commit I would face a problem of not knowing what changes were not on the repo just yet, how would I solve this issue?

These are steps form bitbucket:

Use Git LFS
If the files really need to be part of the Bitbucket repository, use the Large File Storage available on your plan. You can buy more storage if required.

Tell Git to use LFS for specific types of file using a wildcard pattern:

git lfs track ""
For example, to use LFS for MP4 movies:

git lfs track "*.mp4"
*The quotes in the example above are important.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to reduce the size of your repository first, using [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo), as described in "[Two-step push: accelerating Git LFS migration for big repositories](https://nicolas.busseneau.fr/en/blog/2020/12/two-step-push-accelerating-git-lfs-migration-for-big-repositories)".

Once the local repository is small(er), you can activate git LFS and LFS track your larger file (that you restore then).